# Entity Framework code first Inheritance Issue

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have code first implementation for flowing hierarchy,

```
 BaseContact{
   Public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;} 
//..
 }

 Person:BaseContact{

   public string Designation{get;set;} 
//..
 }
Company:BaseContact{
     public int NumOfEmployees{get;set;} 
//..
 }
```

I want to identify person or company with by using only the `Id` value? Currently I am using reflection to identify whether it is a person or company.  Is there any other way to identify it without doing too much?

Comment: What do you want to identify person or company with, by using only the `Id` value?

Comment: Because in MVC layer depending on the type of the object I want to implement several presentation  strategies .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your BaseContact (assume it is an abstract class) add abstract property which will be implemented by other two classes.Use Enum to identify the property type as follows.

```
 public enum MyType
    {
     Person, 
     Company,
    };

    public abstract class BaseContact{
       public abstract MyType ContactType{get;}   
     }

    public class Person:BaseContact
   {

    public override MyType ContactType
    {
      get
      {
        return MyType.Person;
      }      
    }
   }

public class Company:BaseContact
{
    public override MyType ContactType
    {
      get
       {
         return MyType.Company;
       }  
    } 
 }
```

Use your BaseContact repository to retrieve entities and use enum for type separation.

Answer (score 6):

Without seeing how you initialised your classes I'm going to assume you have a table per concrete type approach.

You can't do it just from the ID, as you don't know which table the ID belongs to. ID 2 in "Person" table is a different entity to ID 3 in "Company". The only practical way to identify only from an ID is using a Table per Hierarchy approach and inspecting the type descriptor.

Some good references 
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx

You can also use a simple is statement instead of reflection. Ie `if (entity is Company)`